# How to get PrivateKey for X509Certificate2 with oid differ from 1.2.840....?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have created self-signed certificate using prompt command

```
csptest -keyset -newkeyset -makecert -container test3 -keytype exchange
```

Then I installed it using 3rd-party application. When I am trying to get certificate `PrivateKey` in asp.net core application It throws `NotSupportedException`.

```csharp
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
certificates = store1.Certificates;
var certificate = GetCertificateByThumbprint(certificates, "51F9748FE7DDE895DD100AAD0BE54C1ACF6B4DCC");

if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
{
    var kayAlgorithm = = _certificate.GetKeyAlgorithm(); // same as certificate.PublicKey.Oid.Value;
    var rsaPrivateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    var dsaPrivateKey = _certificate.GetDSAPrivateKey();
    var ecdsaPrivateKey = _certificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
    var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
}
```

`HasPrivateKey` returns true. `GetRSAPrivateKey`, `GetDSAPrivateKey` and `GetECDsaPrivateKey` return null. However `GetKeyAlgorithm` (oid.value) returns "1.2.643.7.1.1.1.1". I went deeper into `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` library and found there hardcoded checking for only "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1" or "1.2.840.10040.4.1" algorithms.

```csharp
public AsymmetricAlgorithm PrivateKey
{
  get
  {
    this.ThrowIfInvalid();
    if (!this.HasPrivateKey)
      return (AsymmetricAlgorithm) null;
    if (this._lazyPrivateKey == null)
    {
      string keyAlgorithm = this.GetKeyAlgorithm();
      if (!(keyAlgorithm == "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"))
      {
        if (!(keyAlgorithm == "1.2.840.10040.4.1"))
          throw new NotSupportedException(SR.NotSupported_KeyAlgorithm);
        this._lazyPrivateKey = (AsymmetricAlgorithm) this.Pal.GetDSAPrivateKey();
      }
      else
        this._lazyPrivateKey = (AsymmetricAlgorithm) this.Pal.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    }
    return this._lazyPrivateKey;
  }
  set
  {
    throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

In .net framework getting `PrivateKey` throws same exception. `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` looks different tho.

```csharp
public AsymmetricAlgorithm PrivateKey
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.HasPrivateKey)
      return (AsymmetricAlgorithm) null;
    if (this.m_privateKey == null)
    {
      CspParameters parameters = new CspParameters();
      if (!X509Certificate2.GetPrivateKeyInfo(this.m_safeCertContext, ref parameters))
        return (AsymmetricAlgorithm) null;
      parameters.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
      switch (this.PublicKey.AlgorithmId)
      {
        case 8704:
          this.m_privateKey = (AsymmetricAlgorithm) new DSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);
          break;
        case 9216:
        case 41984:
          this.m_privateKey = (AsymmetricAlgorithm) new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);
          break;
        default:
          throw new NotSupportedException(SR.GetString("NotSupported_KeyAlgorithm"));
      }
    }
    return this.m_privateKey;
  }
  set
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

So, how can I get `PrivateKey` for different algorithm or did I make something wrong before?

`GetCertificateByThumbprint` method source code just in case. (I could not use `X509Certificate2Collection.Find` method since it does not return my certificate since it is not valid)

```csharp
private X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint(X509Certificate2Collection certifcates, string thumbprint)
    {
        foreach (var certificate in certifcates)
        {
            if (certificate.Thumbprint == thumbprint)
                return certificate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your CSP vendor (GOST) ship API libraries for use in custom applications? Check if they provide extensions for .NET classes. Otherwise, you may need to work with CryptoAPI functions (legacy or CNG) via p/invoke to perform cryptographic operations. Note that these may not be cross-platform. That is, shipped APIs will be available in Windows only.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install Crypto PRO middleware and related software to access the key.

Comment: @Crypt32, well, It seems like crypto pro middleware provide classes for sign messages/data/files. However to create these classes I need certificate and it's private key. There are no special extension methods or such things in examples on crypto pro website. Just certificate.PrivateKey.

Comment: You should consult with Crypto Pro documentation closely. Have you tried to run examples in .NET Framework project? There may be case that Crypto Pro is not compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: @Crypt32, yes, I have created .net framework console app and it throws same error. `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` is a bit different from .net core. I have added source code into original post. Seems it is checking oid too. Just another way.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET has no representation of GOST, there's not really anything useful that the PrivateKey property could return (if it wasn't already effectively deprecated).

From the X509Certificate2 object you can read the `Handle` property to get the underlying OS value (a PCERT_CONTEXT on Windows).  You can then use that to P/Invoke into OS functions, like [CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecertificateprivatekey). Assuming that the GOST CSP is registered with Windows, that function should succeed in returning back a CAPI or CNG key handle (as determined by the dwKeySpec return), which you would then need to continue using with P/Invokes (possibly via a GOST class you make to manage it).